# Add/Update/Delete record to Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have already defined in Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppDbContextConnection")));
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddRazorPages();
}
```

The Tables defined in `AppDbContext.cs` created by `Add-Migration "Initial-Create"` and `Update-Database` :

```
public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
    : base(options){}
public DbSet<Table1> SomeItems { get; set; }
public DbSet<Table2> SomeOtherItems { get; set; }
```

`Table1.cs` model looks like this:

```
public class Table1
{
    [Required]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int item1 { get; set; }
    public int item2 { get; set; }
    public int item3 { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to know how to simply Read, Add, Update or Remove records to database?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/crud?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score -1):

you can just use the dbContext

i.e.

```
dbContext.Table1.Add(entity)
dbContext.Table2.Add(entity)
```

or

```
var dbSet1 = dbContext.Set<Table1>();
dbSet1.Add(entity);

var dbSet2 = dbContext.Set<Table2>();
dbSet2.Add(entity);
```

For Removing you can just call the `Remove` method on the DbContext or on the DbSet.

For Reading you can either use the DbSet which holds entities of the specified type

```
//Will return a dbSet for the Table1 entity
var dbSet1 = dbContext.Set<Table1>();
//Will return all entity with Id=1
dbSet1.Where(entity => entity.Id == 1);
```

For retrieving an entity by id you can use the `Find` method.

Comment: I’d advise against a generic repository pattern. When designing the interaction between the application logic and the database, it should be thought about on a case by case basis. A generic repository is an anti pattern imo.

Comment: Remove generic repository pattern and EF6 links.